# Nginx proxy_set_header meaning

Tags: nginx, proxy, header, reverse-proxy

I followed a tutorial to serve static content with Nginx that told me to use these three proxy headers.

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

However, I never understood the meaning behind them, and I can't find a good explanation.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: These headers only have meaning in a reverse proxy. They are used by the `proxy_pass` directive to construct the request to the upstream server. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

Comment: I get that however, i don't understand the field and value purpose 
X-Real-IP $remote_addr and X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for

Comment: The X headers are common non-standard headers which convey the IP address of the client through a reverse proxy.